# Java Game Hitbox Detection & Rounded Corners

Tags: java, swing, intersection, rectangles

I am working on a simple 2D game with Java, swing and no framework. I have a rectangular player that the user can move around. On the map are few obstacles which the player should not be able to go through. I did this by making a new Rectangle Object for the player and each obstacle with their bounds. But I’m not really sure if this is the right way to do it. It works but the movements of the player are not really user friendly. If the player wants to pass two obstacles they must be on the perfect coordinates to pass.

Is it even a good idea to check for intersections between the player and the obstacle with a Rectangle object or should I do it another way?

Now for my 2nd question:
I’d like to replace the rectangular hitboxes with the same hitbox but with rounded corners so the player could pass more easily.

[image: My game with hitboxes enabled]

This is what the game looks like with hitboxes enabled.

The code that checks if the player and the obstacles have yet intersected:

```
for (Player p : this.getPlayerArray()) {
    Rectangle recPlayer = p.playerBounds();
        for (Obstacle kiste : obstacleArray) {
            Rectangle recKiste = kiste.obstBounds();

            if (recPlayer.intersects(recKiste)) {
                p.setX(100); //Not actual code here
            }
        }
}
```

The function that returns the hitbox of the player / obstacle:

```
public Rectangle obstBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(this.getX(), 
    this.getY(), image.getImage().getWidth(null), 
    image.getImage().getHeight(null));
}
```

Comment: I think you can make the collision be based on a tile map-like system.

Comment: @GiantTree Thats how I created the map. But it is all self coded. Is there a difference with tile map detection?

Comment: Just for clarification: Are you moving on a tile map or is there free movement. If your player is moving on a tile map, you can just check if the tile you want to move to is passable and move accordingly.

Comment: @GiantTree I have different obstacle types. Some that the player should not pass and others that act as the ground / background. I would like to round the corners of the obstacle hitboxes the player should collide with.

Comment: You could use a [RoundRectangle2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RoundRectangle2D.html) for your collision box, but the docs state that the `intersects()` method is just an approximation, because the logic is too complex for a precise check. Also it can only check if a `Rectangle` is intersecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many years ago I wrote a Khepera simulator as part of my undergrads' final year project. I started by doing collision detection as you are doing, that is intersecting areas... My supervisor made me notice that since the shape of my robot was a circle I just could check if the center of the robot was inside another shape, if that was the case a collision occured.

Your case is even simpler since you move on tiles... so either you do (as suggested in the comments) maintain a set of "move/no move" tiles and check that, or you just check that the position of your player is within, or not, a 'forbidden' rectangle, i.e. an obstacle. If it is, then you have to reset the position of the character to be 'outside' of the obstacle (minus the character's bounding box, obviously)

I strongly suggest to do it the tiles way: allow only up/down/left/right movements and check against a 'forbidden' set of movements given a tile-position. If you really want 'freedom' of movements than go with circles (bounding boxes/circles) because they are easy to reason with, easy to do a position reset (in case of collisions) and perfect for your case (every tile can contain a circle, whether an obstacle or the player.)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about collision checking, but I think a simple approach would do just fine for your use-case.

First from the looks of your screenshot, a tile is either an obstacle or passable, but never half of each. In that case it would be simplest to just check on which tile the *center* (or feet, choose what looks best) of the character are.

If its an obstacle, they can*t* go there, simple as that. Note that this will allow the player to move partially *into* an obstacle, but many games do it this way and players are certainly used to this behavior, especially in 2D games with graphics designed to look like an isometric projection (which I would yours class as). A variation of this would be to simply make the player collision rectangle smaller (say half a tile, again centered at the player sprites chest or feet).